# Polar coordinates questions

Tags: dynamical-systems

Using polar coordinates, create a system with a fixed point at the origin, and with infinitely many periodic orbits which alternate between clockwise and counterclockwise flows.

Comment: You might want to edit the title of this question.

Comment: Why did you delete the body of the question?

Comment: in general it is vastly preferable that we keep the contents of question statements as self-contained on this website as possible. Therefore I reverted your edit which replaced the above question Text with a Linked Image. Your edits to this question may be interpreted as borderline vandalism, please refrain from that in the future.

Comment: Please do not ask questions in imperative.

Answer (score 1):

$re^{i\theta} \longrightarrow re^{i(\theta+ (-1)^{[\frac{r}{2 \pi}]}r)} $

Answer (score 0):

start with circles $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\mapsto(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$.  now vary the magnitude, say by $\sin r$:
$$
(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\mapsto(\sin r)(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)
$$